# Merge three images in graphics magic

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I need to merge three images by using graphicsmagik library in node.js, but it is still showing two images. I want like images to be merged in this way first image to be shown and remaining two images merged up and down which will be merged with the first image just like skype group image. Something like

```
+---+---+---+---+
| user1 | user2 |
|       |---+---+
|       | user3 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

below is my code

```
gm()
    .in('-page', '+0+0')
    .in('http://localhost:8080/user1')
    .in('-page', '+50+0')
    .in('http://localhost:8080/user2')
    .in('-page', '+100+0')
    .in('http://localhost:8080/user3')
    .mosaic()
    .write('E:/images/output1.jpg', function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: try  with  .in('-page', '+50+50'), at line 6 of your code.

Comment: Thanks Luca...yes with .in('-page', '+50+50') and by putting minify() then it worked. Also Luca I need to know one more thing how I can increase the length of first image, I have also used resize method but it didn't worked.

Comment: Your code looks pretty good to me. I can only suggest you make a couple of local images to try it out without the `http://...` stuff, and that you write your output file to the local directory to rule out the `E:/...` stuff.